# Show that the family $E_\mu$ undergoes tangential bifurcation

Tags: bifurcation

Let $E_\mu(x)=\mu e^x$. Show that the family $E_\mu$ undergoes tangential bifurcation at $\mu=1/e$. In particular follow out the following steps:

(a)  Plot out the diagonal and the graph of $E_\mu (x)$ for $\mu < 1/e$,  $\mu=1/e$, and $\mu>1/e$.

(b) Calculate the partial derivative.

(c) Do the fixed points occur for $\mu<1/e$   or $\mu>1/e$.

As you can see, I was able to execute part (a), but I am entirely confused on how to calculate the partial derivatives, which would lead me to the fixed points in part (c) I believe.

[image]

Comment: My browser didn't typeset the title, so I was a bit disappointed to see that this question had nothing to do with emus.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom:  solid, goodcomment, +1!